# model binding nested objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm using a ViewModel to get the data from the HTML form to the MVC controller.
In the ActionResult parameter, there is the ViewModel that is filled, it's working fine.

Now, I want to get one field of the viewmodel separated in addition to the viewmodel. Is it possible? In another word, I want a copy of MyViewModel.MyModel.Id into another actionresult parameter.

Here is the working Controller Method:

```
public ActionResult Edit(AuditViewModelCritereViewModel model){}
```

Now I want to have this kind of method

```
public ActionResult Edit(AuditViewModelCritereViewModel model, int auditId){}
```

Here are the Models:

```
public class AuditViewModelCritereViewModel
    {
        public AuditViewModel audit { get; set; }
        ...
    }

public class AuditViewModel 
    {
        public int auditId { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

I could achieve this by adding HiddenField but clean is the best, I would like to make this prettier than copiing HTML id value.

In the HTML form, here is the field:

```
<input data-val="true" id="audit_auditId" name="audit.auditId" type="hidden" value="10">
```

This is HTTP request content that interest us:

[image: http header]

This is what I've tried so far as int paramater:

- int auditId
- int audit_auditId

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes it is possible**

```
 <input data-val="true" id="audit_auditId" name="auditId" type="hidden" value="10">
```

Take same **name** of input field where you want to get the data in action parameter.

***Action Parameter name and Field name should be same. It will works fine***

OR

You can get this things with using Bind Attribute in Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(AuditViewModelCritereViewModel model, [Bind(Prefix = "audit.auditId")]int auditId) { }
```

Comment: "I could achieve this by adding HiddenField but clean is the best, I would like to make this prettier than copiing HTML id value."

Comment: You should try this one works for me - public ActionResult Edit(AuditViewModelCritereViewModel model, [Bind(Prefix = "audit.auditId")]int auditId) { }